# Why does cPanel not have the icon I'm looking for?

Tags: cpanel

I want to forward all emails to a central address. For this I need to setup the default email address.

**My cpanel does not have the "Default Address" icon in the email section.**

[image: Default Address icon in cPanel]

Why it is not there? How can I enable it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask your hosting provider. Your web host has probably disabled this feature within your hosting account (ie. cPanel).

The "Default Address" (ie. a *catch all*) can place an increased load on the mailserver if (when) you start getting a lot of spam. Some shared hosts will disable this feature for this reason.

Comment: In general, a default address should not be used because it will most just catch spam. If you have a number of email addresses that need to go to another address. Create forwarders.  You will be better served with 1000 forwarding addresses than a catch-all email in case you get hit with a dictionary attack.